# ConfigurationManager can't find App.config .NET4

Tags: null, app-config, configurationmanager, assign

first question on StackOverflow so please be kind.

My DLL application can't find the App.config I've manually added to the project. I use the ConfigurationManager like this:

```java
string rootMailTemplate = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootMailTemplate"];
```

And the piece of my xml configuration file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RootMailTemplate" value="D:\Exercise\MailManagement\" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But somehow refuses to take the value and its null when I run my tests.

Any idea why? Please let me know if you need more info!

Edit: Fixed:

Ok fellas, fixed, app.config for test must be on the test project too. The accessor has access to functions and methods but not to the additional files.